# Initializing this.applicationContext in Spring

Tags: java, spring, applicationcontext

Unfortunately, I've recently become responsible for a Spring project because our Spring expert left for greener pastures. "Unfortunately" because while I know Java well, I know little about [Spring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework) except its [basic principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) and I'm expected to continue quickly advancing this project.

I'm blocked by this exception

`Cannot invoke "org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext.getBean(java.lang.Class)" because "this.applicationContext is null"`

which is raised when running this unit test

```
    @Test
    public void testAnalyzeMetadata() throws DataException, IOException, BadJSONException {
        new IRWMetadataAnalyzer().analyzeMetadata( 10, "no file");
    }
```

The test class is annotated with

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@DataJdbcTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace=AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@Commit
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"org.ms.IRWMetadataIntegration"})
```

like other test classes and methods that don't raise this exception.

Reviewing the project, I don't find any initialization of `applicationContext` in the working tests and code under test, so that clearly happens "under the sheets". But I cannot determine where or how.

What I really need is a great consultant / trainer, but SO is my best alternative for now.

Thanks

Arthur

Comment: Maybe I just missed that, but what is `IRWMetadataAnalyzer`? Is this a custom class? Could be relevant how `this.applicationContext` is accessed here.